# Probability using C(n,k) 1

Tags: probability

A family of five children is known to have at least two girls.What is the probability of this family having exactly four girls?

Comment: You're missing some data: we need to know how likely it is to have a girl or a boy, and we need to know if there's any dependence between subsequent birth sexes.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Next time please do post your approach.

So out of the 3 remaining children you need exactly 2 girls $\implies$ 2 girls and 1 boy.

So probability = $\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2}.3\{for~ arranging\}=\frac{3}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

Make the usual independence, and equal likelihood of boy and girl assumptions, knowing they are not quite correct.

Let $A$ be the event "exactly $4$ girls" and $B$ be the event "at least $2$ girls."
We want $\Pr(A|B)$. Recall that
$$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}.$$
The event $A\cap B$ is the same as the event $A$, and has probability $\dfrac{\binom{5}{4}}{2^5}$.

The event $B$ has probability $1-\dfrac{\binom{5}{0}}{2^5}-\dfrac{\binom{5}{1}}{2^5}=\dfrac{26}{2^5}$.

Divide. We get $\dfrac{5}{26}$.